# Inconsistent crash at boost::thread::release_handle?

Tags: c++, boost

How can I check where the fault happened?

The crash is inconsistent, here is a sample dump:

```
00000000`1ae7c850 000007fe`d675a8be : 00000000`0000005e 00000000`2082cb20 00000000`00000000 00000000`20539b00 : boost_thread_vc140_mt_1_62!boost::thread::release_handle+0x26
00000000`1ae7c890 000007fe`d675a802 : 00000000`1ae7c930 00000000`2082cb20 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e2fc57d9 : boost_thread_vc140_mt_1_62!boost::thread::join_noexcept+0x8e
00000000`1ae7c910 000007fe`d23c674b : 000007fe`d2571e10 000007fe`d2614ef0 000007fe`d2614ef0 00000000`00000000 : boost_thread_vc140_mt_1_62!boost::thread::join+0xe2
00000000`1ae7c9d0 000007fe`d2401c94 : 00000000`03d443b0 00000000`03d443b0 00000000`20ff0000 00000000`03d443b0 : ABC::StopProcessMonitor+0x18b
```

The relevant code is:

```
class ABC {
    boost::scoped_ptr<boost::thread> m_threadMonitor;
    HANDLE m_hShouldStop;
};

void ABC::StopProcessMonitor() {
    if (m_threadMonitor) {
        LOG_INFO() << L"Stop monitor thread.";

        ::SetEvent(m_hShouldStop);

        m_threadMonitor->join();
        m_threadMonitor.reset();

        ::CloseHandle(m_hShouldStop);
        m_hShouldStop = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] please.  That is a complete, but small, working program that demonstrates the issue that we can copy, compile, and run ourselves.  What you have is not sufficient to reveal the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Since the crash is inconsistent, you probably have a race condition.  Try thinking though all of the code that is interacting with the thread, test cases can help verify that.

I've had good success with [Clang's Thread Sanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) for similar problems.